# Android Studio Not Recognizing Application Name on Update to 2.2.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, android-studio-2.2

I recently updated Android Studio to version 2.2.2 and have been experiencing some issues, among them my application name is no longer being recognized in the manifest. I also migrated to the new Firebase SDK based on the documentation located [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android):

[image]

I am not exactly sure of the cause, but have been reading about multidexing as being one of the components related to this error. I am also receiving a run-time error below that I believe also relates to the issue:

```
--------- beginning of crash
11-28 20:29:06.313 10163-10163/com.troychuinard.fanpolls E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       Process: com.troychuinard.fanpolls, PID: 10163
       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.troychuinard.fanpolls.FanPollsApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.troychuinard.fanpolls.FanPollsApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.troychuinard.fanpolls-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.troychuinard.fanpolls-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:578)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.troychuinard.fanpolls.FanPollsApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.troychuinard.fanpolls-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.troychuinard.fanpolls-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:981)
       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:573)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.troychuinard.fanpolls.FanPollsApplication
       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 12 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Build.Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'


defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    applicationId "com.troychuinard.fanpolls"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
  }
}
repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.3'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
 }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my directory structure:

[image]

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to clean/rebuild your project or Invalidate Caches/Restart?

Comment: I have tried cleaning/rebuilding several times, what does invalidating caches actually do?

Comment: Change minifyEnabled false to true. Clean the project, rebuild and check.

Comment: Tried it, did not work

Comment: Try going to File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart

Comment: Tried, still the same error. Starting to think it has to do with the Firebase migration....

Comment: Check that the source file for class `FanPollsApplication` is in folder `.../app/src/main/java/com/troychuinard/fanpolls`.  The red highlight in your manifest indicates it is not there.

Comment: Can you show us your FanPollsApplication.java? Atleast, is it already has Multidex.install(this);

Comment: the thing is I do not have a FanPollsApplication class......

Comment: @qbix I have added the directory structure. I do not have a FanPollsApplication class. However, I am confused why it previously worked as I did not have a FanPollsApplication class before either...

Comment: Maybe the new version of Android Studio enforces that you really have an application class with that name. Just dropping off the attribute name='.FanPollsApplication' should do the work.

Comment: This is about the third time you've posted a very similar variation of this question. I have removed the other duplicates. Please avoid duplicating content in the future. If you have new information to add to a question and it hasn't received any responses yet, simply **edit** the question to update it instead of posting a new one. This will even bump your question to the front page again, so you're not losing any benefits.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that editing bumped it back to the top, moving forward I will note!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't have a class `com.troychuinard.fanpolls.FanPollsApplication`, just remove the attribute `name='.FanPollsApplication'`. It will use standard `android.app.Application` instead.

Comment: Much appreciated, I am just unsure why it ran without issues previously and now it is not working unless I remove the name attribute

Answer (score 1):

I think when you add firebase,  you application is over 64k methods and you need to follow this link about MultiDex

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html